# Solving Gaussian Integral

Tags: gaussian-integral

I learned that a Gaussian Integral is
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-2ax^2}dx=0
\end{equation}
Because of the odd function symmetry.
But if I shift the $x$ to
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-2a(x-x_0)^2}dx
\end{equation}
then how to solve this integral?

Comment: Add and subtract $x_0$ in the $x = x-x_0 + x_0$. Then you have two integrals you know the answer to.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I see, thank you!

Comment: Btw the Gaussian Integral is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-2a(x-x_0)^2}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x-x_0)e^{-2a(x-x_0)^2}dx + x_0 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2a(x-x_0)^2}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-2ax^2}dx + x_0 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2ax^2}dx$$
$$=x_0\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}$$

Comment: I see, thank you!